# Mechanism for old drop arm chaise lounge

Tags: hinges

I am renovating an old chaise lounge.  The drop down arm was braced and nailed in place.  I would like to find a mechanism for inside the chaise that I could use to move the arm from almost upright to almost flat.  The radius of the arm base and curve of the chaise base is 4" and they move in the same plane.[image: chaise base and arm[![base and arm][image: ][![[]1][1]][inside arm]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKkJM.jpg)

[image: chaise base]

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE! Unfortunately, product recommendations are off-topic

Comment: @mmathis, this isn't that type of request. It's a call for a *type* of thing, which we've had here dozens of times before.

Comment: Jean, from the marks on the wood it looks like it originally had a pivoting mechanism with the fulcrum a few inches from the curve (possibly the hole near the webbing in the 2nd photo) which may tell you how this was done originally, and I bet it was based on a ratchet mechanism. I don't know that there's anything currently available *retail* that does this, but only recently I saw a headrest on a sofa that must use something similar internally.